# How to replace placeholder locations with properties from the same object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using typescript. Please include answers supporting typescript also.

Following is an object with some deep properties.

```
const startObject = {
    Hardware: {propertiesFromhardware: {}},
    Software: {propertiesFromsoftware: {}},
    Middleware: {propertiesFromDown: {}},
    electronics: {hardware_c: "Hardware", otherProperty1: {hardware_e: "Hardware", otherSubProperty1: {}}, otherProperty2: {}},
    tech_items: {software_d: "Software", otherProperty1: {otherSubProperty1: {middleware_r: "Middleware", }}},
    gadgets:{hardware_t: "Hardware", software_d: "Software", otherProperty1: {otherSubProperty1: {middleware_r: "Middleware", }}},
}
```

Where ever you see "Hardware", "Software" or "Middleware", it should get replaced with values from the following object - no matter how deep they are.

So that the final result will be:
expected result

```
// this is what we get when the startObject is transformed
// note that after removing all the occurences of "Hardware"/ "Software" / "Middleware"; these values will be removed so that final result looks like this. (with all placeholders replaced"

const finalObject = {
    electronics: {hardware_c: {propertiesFromhardware: {}, otherproperties...}, otherProperty1: {hardware_e: {propertiesFromhardware: {}, otherproperties...}, otherSubProperty1: {}}, otherProperty2: {}},
    tech_items: {software_d: {propertiesFromsoftware: {}, otherproperties...}, otherProperty1: {otherSubProperty1: {middleware_r: {propertiesFromDown: {}, otherproperties...}, }}},
    gadgets:{hardware_t: {propertiesFromhardware: {}, otherproperties...}, software_d: {propertiesFromsoftware: {}, otherproperties...}, otherProperty1: {otherSubProperty1: {middleware_r: {propertiesFromDown: {}, otherproperties...}, }}},
}
```

**Note that this should replace all the deep occurences of "Hardware", "Software" or "Middleware" with corresponding values**

Comment: Flagging as `needs improvement`, have you done any testing or research for replace algorithms? What you're asking for is that someone else solves your problem.

Comment: No. I've tried a lot.

Comment: I'm not being able to replace all placeholders at all levels, eventhough I;m being able to do it at first level. That's why I posted.

Comment: Can you post your code so we can review it?

Answer (score 1):

In order for TypeScript to have a hope of understanding the placeholder replacement, you will need to make sure the placeholders in `startObject`'s properties are of [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) and not just `string`.  TypeScript's compiler tends to widen string literals to `string` unless it has some hint not to do that.  The easiest way to modify your code so that the compiler remembers `startObject`'s literal string properties is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const startObject = { ... } as const;
```

This will also have the effect of making all properties `readonly`, which probably doesn't matter much to you.

---

After this, we need to represent the placeholder replacement both in the type system and in the runtime code.  The type system replacement code looks something like this:

```
type DeepReplace<T extends object, K extends keyof T> =
  DeepReplaceInner<Omit<T, K>, Pick<T, K>> extends
  infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never

type DeepReplaceInner<T, U> = {
  [K in keyof T]: (T[K] extends keyof U ? U[T[K]] : DeepReplaceInner<T[K], U>) extends
  infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
}
```

The idea is that `DeepReplace<typeof startObject, "Hardware" | "Software" | "MiddleWare"` will evaluate to the type of `finalObject`.  The definition of `DeepReplace` splits the passed in object type `T` into the base part `Omit<T, K>` and the replacement part `Pick<T, K>`, and then passes into the recursive `DeepReplaceInner<T, U>`.

`DeepReplaceInner<T, U>` walks through properties of `T`.  If any of the values are one of the keys of `U` (the replacement), the returned property comes from the relevant value of `U`.  Otherwise it returns `DeepReplaceInner` for the property of `T`.

There's a lot of type juggling there but that's the gist of it.

---

Then, the runtime code could look like this:

```
function deepReplace<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T, 
  keys: K[]
): DeepReplace<T, K>;

function deepReplace(obj: any, keys: PropertyKey[]) {
  const base: any = Object.assign({}, obj);
  const repl: any = {};
  for (const k of keys) {
    repl[k] = base[k];
    delete base[k];
  }
  function deepReplaceInner(base: any, repl: any) {
    if (typeof obj !== "object" || obj === null) return obj;
    const ret: any = {};
    for (const k in base) {
      ret[k] = (base[k] in repl) ? repl[base[k]] : deepReplaceInner(base[k], repl);
    }
    return ret;
  }
  return deepReplaceInner(base, repl);
}
```

I've used an [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to separate the generic call signature from the `any`-filled implementation.  The implementation looks a lot like a runtime version of the type signature: split `obj` into `base` and `repl` based on the keys in `keys`, and then call `deepReplaceInner(base, repl)`, which walks through the properties of `base` and replaces any properties that are keys of `repl` with the corresponding value from `repl`, and otherwise recurses down.

---

Let's see if it works:

```
const finalObject = deepReplace(startObject, ["Hardware", "Software", "Middleware"]);
```

You can verify that the type system is working because IntelliSense knows that the following leaf properties exist:

```
finalObject.electronics.hardware_c.propertiesFromhardware;
finalObject.electronics.otherProperty1.hardware_e.propertiesFromhardware;
finalObject.electronics.otherProperty1.otherSubProperty1;
finalObject.gadgets.hardware_t.propertiesFromhardware;
finalObject.gadgets.otherProperty1.otherSubProperty1;
finalObject.gadgets.software_d.propertiesFromsoftware;
```

finalObject.tech_items.otherProperty1.otherSubProperty1.middleware_r.propertiesFromDown;
    finalObject.tech_items.software_d.propertiesFromsoftware;

And you can verify that the runtime code works by examining the output of

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(finalObject));
```

Both look good to me.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

See [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBNCGAnKB5ARgKwKbFgXhgG8BYAKBhgAkkATAdySwC4iYAHRENrZASywgAxTgFsAFrQaJmRAL4xZAGjIUAyiABmUKTMLtO3PgOEgRETdsYtC8pSpgBZXjRoAbLDuv6uPKPyGiACIgdGDWtsrkMFjuuJxgvMAQ1vYUEoj0jAD6wCwARNQZOnmKMCBQYjwACga+AJ4AjF7pmdJZMgWSjCVlFTyqAK5oNT7IjeEKpeWViCOGUHUATOH2dlFQOGJZvBtmXuZaOlk0+eqH3VN9s7VjTazT-UNz9Xd6Is5uHtmI+U4u7sVSrZJvYAObwGigrBQZKsFpHKD5QqtLA9A6WNonGB5M4Y1GXGbPW5eB6IQbDG4LV4wd7-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-N4WcFzbG0SJgABCPACDyEj9TyGAAB92rKTBHUakCBlcVwH2kKABkQH8SOinlwAUkaSvs2Qpuc1yF3c81vwS8KyqiCgKBGyL1LyxLgo2gKH1zAK83yyLj0QzLUMvRAjvCyKitlMy-JS3b-OhMafxG5L7BGv67u4rLexyp78re90Poglt3I0VN4FcdBsFwdSuLPVCFwQZA0f1Uo806IoLmxXFWTyZkAW6WjWOR1HNK0mJ9XiRIIC0+FsmALSOFGPxjFELnpHpsAUYJ3BmdiKA2aSLTSXExpOa6NosF5yl-BMcQVawUXxaZlm4nAdn5auRWGlNmZyXNvXGfR7TwUhaEOeFrAsm0vn5k1oWddtiWHYhKEYUt6pKSV0lrbDho-aZx2g459EjhodX+e90xE8YGP7a0jZgC2HYsDMEPrn58Orkj0uLdpFlvhTr3BdMYJQiz-Uc82bZdgTiwk7r3w07MbvM5bMh5JAdwtNcEBQQXAApVQUAAOS06BEFTUEKrqBckbFu39TvOGgA) for working code

Comment: Good answer, but it may have been better to see the individual's working out before providing them with a working solution.